# reactで西暦を和暦で表示する方法

Tags: reactjs

<InputDateAsNumber isYM value={dayjs().format("YYYYMMDD")} />
で表示すると
2021/09
と表示されます。

R3/09
のように表示するにはどのようにすればいいでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

[`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) が利用可能かと思います。

```js
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ja-JP-u-ca-japanese',{year:'numeric', month: '2-digit'}).format(new Date()));
```